I need help with code with two IR sensors using ATMega16
I'm working on a ball-counting project using two IR sensors to detect balls entering and exiting a room, but I'm currently stuck. I need help refining the logic in my while loop. Here's how I want it to function:
The first sensor detects a ball.
The first sensor stops detecting.
The second sensor detects the ball.
The second sensor stops detecting.
The counter should increase or decrease depending on which sensor detected the ball first.
Right now, my code only works when both sensors detect an object at the same time.
if (!(PINA & (1<<PA0))) { //Check S1
    
    while (!(PINA & (1<<PA0)));

    // Now check if S2 is detecting
    if (!(PINA & (1<<PA1))) {
    
        while (!(PINA & (1<<PA1)));

        // Increment the visitor count
        visitor_count++;
    }
}

// Check if S2 is detecting
if (!(PINA & (1<<PA1))) { 
    while (!(PINA & (1<<PA1)));

    // Now check if S1 is detecting
    if (!(PINA & (1<<PA0))) {
        // Wait for S1 to stop detecting
        while (!(PINA & (1<<PA0)));

        // Decrement the visitor count
        visitor_count--;
    }
}

The first sensor detects
The second sensor detects
The first sensor stops detecting
The second sensor stops detecting
Counter increases or decreases
But sensors are not close enough and will never detect a ball at the same time. I tried asking ChatGPT, but it keeps giving me the same answer. I thought you’ll understand better my problem.
I will appreciate any advice.
Edit: There is just one entrance, with two sensors.

You need to implement a state machine. A state machine is such a common solution that if you do not know what one is, now would be a great time to learn.

A common method to count objects (balls or people) in a space with only 1 opening (entrance / exit) is to use 2 beam interruption detectors placed close enough such that the object of interest will, at some point while entering or exiting the space, block both beams at the same time. Specifically, one beam will be blocked, then both and finally the other beam will be blocked. To detect the object's direction (entering or exiting) a well understood method called quadrature decoding is used. As this is a common solution, it is likely what the AI assumed was requested.
In the above case, a simple 4 state machine can be implement to detect direction of travel. Let's call the beams A and B. The 4 states are simply 1) no beams blocked, 2) only beam A blocked, 3) both beam B & A blocked & 4) only beam B blocked. The object counter can be incremented or decremented depending on the direction of travel of the object. Assumptions are made that only 1 object will pass the detector at a time and that the object will completely pass the detector without changing direction.
If the detectors are spaced far enough apart that they both can not be blocked by the same object at the same time, the solution can remain identical to the above. However, we will not be able to know for sure which of 2 of the above stats (no beams blocked and both beams blocked) we are in. So we need to make an additional assumption. There can only be 1 object between the 2 detectors at any given time. If true, we sill only need 4 states. But the state where both beams are blocked will need to be changed to be identical to the state where no beams are blocked. They will be identical except one of these identical states will represent no object between the detectors and the other an object between the detectors.
To conclude, the 1st design is more robust and and harder to confuse in the real world (where assumptions are often disregarded). The 2nd design is less robust and can be confused easily in the real world.

The issue lies in the order of operations and the logic that checks the sensors. You want the logic to handle cases where a ball could be detected by one sensor first and the other sensor shortly after, depending on the direction of travel. You can modify the code like this:
// Variables to keep track of the sensor states
bool s1_detected = false;
bool s2_detected = false;

if (!(PINA & (1<<PA0))) { // Check if S1 detects first
    s1_detected = true;
    
    // Wait for S1 to stop detecting
    while (!(PINA & (1<<PA0)));

    // Now check if S2 detects after S1
    if (!(PINA & (1<<PA1))) {
        s2_detected = true;
        
        // Wait for S2 to stop detecting
        while (!(PINA & (1<<PA1)));

        // Increment the visitor count
        if (s1_detected && s2_detected) {
            visitor_count++;
        }

        // Reset detection states
        s1_detected = false;
        s2_detected = false;
    }
}

// Check if S2 detects first
if (!(PINA & (1<<PA1))) { 
    s2_detected = true;
    
    // Wait for S2 to stop detecting
    while (!(PINA & (1<<PA1)));

    // Now check if S1 detects after S2
    if (!(PINA & (1<<PA0))) {
        s1_detected = true;

        // Wait for S1 to stop detecting
        while (!(PINA & (1<<PA0)));

        // Decrement the visitor count
        if (s2_detected && s1_detected) {
            visitor_count--;
        }

        // Reset detection states
        s1_detected = false;
        s2_detected = false;
    }
}


When S1 detects a ball, the code waits until S1 stops detecting. Then it checks if S2 detects the ball next. If it does, and then S2 stops detecting, it increments the counter.
If S2 detects the ball first, the code waits for S2 to stop detecting, then checks if S1 detects next. If so, the counter is decremented.
Hopefully, this method will work. If you also need guidelines regarding how to interface IR sensors with ATmega16, you can check here:
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/Interfacing_IR_Sensor_Module_with_Arduino_Nano_31dcd7c1.html

That is exactly the code snippet, that OP posted in their question. You haven't modified anything, besides some comments.

Thanks. Edited.
